# Increasing the speed of speech without changing the pitch

Tags: audio, openal

I use OpenAL library to change the speed of speech. My problem is that if I change the pitch it makes the speaker sound like a smurf. I found out that this could be solved by using  algorithms like WSOLA that don't create this negative effect. So is there a support in OpenAL for that?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenAL does not directly implement processing like WSOLA. The only audio processing that OpenAL has ever done directly was through EAX/EFX and even then it was mostly for commonly used effects like reverb, distortion, ect.

With that said, there's nothing that stops you from accessing your audio buffer directly and passing it onto your WSOLA algorithm, and then playing back the finished data using OpenAL.